# Can't connect to a ec2 windows instance after I have enabled Enhanced Networking with ENA

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

My problem started when I couldn't change an EC2 instance type from a c4.large to a c5.large because I get an error message saying that I have first to enable Enhanced Networking, then I googled how to enabled it and I found the following article:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/enhanced-networking-ena.html

After I followed all the directions on that article and now that I get "true" as the response when I execute the AWS command to verify if now ENA is enabled"

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-ids i-044c2234g8e22csad36 --query "Reservations[].Instances[].EnaSupport"
True
```

I can now start my instance as a c5.large with no errors but I can't connect to it using Microsoft Remote Desktop client, unless I change it back to a c4.large type instance. I was wondering if I need to configure something in the network after this change, which is not explained in the documentation above mentioned, so please if anybody could help me to figure this out would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you also install the driver on the instance? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/enhanced-networking-ena.html#enable-enhanced-networking-ena-WIN

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I did, I followed the instructions there.